# Why will Timer not work inside of for loop?

Tags: java

I have this timer set inside of each element of a list.
With a for loop I'd like to execute each timer event of each element in each iteration. However the code executes but the timer does not seem to work, all the elements get listed immediately. What is the cause of this?

I've summarized the code to include only the essential.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        playList playList = new playList();

        Song song1 = new Song("song 1", "artist 1", 2000);
        playList.add(song1);
        Song song2 = new Song("song 2", "artist 2", 3000);
        playList.add(song2);
        Song song3 = new Song("song 3", "artist 3", 3500);
        playList.add(song3);
        Song song4 = new Song("song 4", "artist 4", 3500);
        playList.add(song4);

        playList.playThisList();

    }
}

class Song {
    String title;
    String artist;
    int duration;

    public Song(String title, String artist, int duration) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.artist + ", " + this.title;
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run () { stop(); } };


    public void play() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, duration, duration);
        System.out.println("Now Playing");
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.cancel();
    }
}

class playList () {
    void playThisList()  {
        System.out.println("Playlist");
        Node node = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            node.song.play();
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can use `Thread.sleep()` but I still want to understand why its not possible to use Timer here, or how can I use it in this case?

Comment: Do you want each song to play repeatedly? Do you want all the songs playing concurrently? I get that impression from the code you posted in your question but I just wanted to be sure that I am not mistaken.

Comment: This code won't compile as it is, but if I guess the missing bits, what it does is call `play` on all four songs straight away, starting four independent timers with tasks that do nothing apart from stopping the timer. These timers run all at the same time and the program exits when the last one fires (after 3500ms). As Abra says, try and explain what you want to happen in a bit more detail.

Comment: I have a linked list with elements called ```song```. Each song has a ```play``` method that has a timer as shown in the code. I want to be able to iterate over the linked list executing the ```play``` method(and its timer) for each element. When I execute the code it executes all lines instantly and the timers seem to be ignored. I dont understand why. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterHull has explained to you why _the timers seem to be ignored_ in his comment. The timers are not ignored, they are immediately stopped because that is how you have coded them. Your code works. So it appears that you want your code to do something else but you don't know how to write the code to achieve what you want. If that is true, then [edit] your question and write what you want the code to do. Do you want all the songs to play at the same time? Or do you want them to play one after the other? Do you want each song to play once only or more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes, which I think do what you want whilst sticking close to the 'spirit' of your code. Maybe compare this with yours and see if that helps.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        playList playList = new playList();

        Song song1 = new Song("song 1", "artist 1", 2000);
        playList.add(song1);
        Song song2 = new Song("song 2", "artist 2", 3000);
        playList.add(song2);
        Song song3 = new Song("song 3", "artist 3", 3500);
        playList.add(song3);
        Song song4 = new Song("song 4", "artist 4", 3500);
        playList.add(song4);

        playList.playThisList();

    }
}

class Song {

    String title;
    String artist;
    int duration;

    public Song(String title, String artist, int duration) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.artist + ", " + this.title;
    }

    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Now Playing: " + this);
    }

}

class playList {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Node head = null;

    void add(Song s) {
        head = new Node(head, s);
    }

    void playThisList() {
        System.out.println("Playlist");
        playThisNode(head);
    }

    void playThisNode(Node node) {
        node.song.play();
        final Node next = node.next;
        if (next != null) {
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    playThisNode(next);
                }
            }, node.song.duration);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Done");
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    class Node {

        public Node(Node next, Song song) {
            this.song = song;
            this.next = next;
        }
        final Song song;
        final Node next;
    }
}
```

It does play the songs in reverse order but I'm sure you can fix that!